# convert datetime to yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert a datetime object to the format yyyy/MM/dd? I am trying this:

```
DateTime selectedDate =Convert.ToDateTime( Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(selectedDate, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

or

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to convert a string to a `DateTime`, or a `DateTime` to a string?

Comment: This is a poor question, re-read what you have written then amend it so that it's clear and makes sense. As the others have said, the error message is clear and precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime` does not have an inherent format - only an internal representation.

Formatting comes into play when you want to *display* the value of the `DateTime` instance:

```
string formatted = DateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The above `formatted` string will contain the values of the `DateTime` instance in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

Date format makes sense when you are going to convert it to string or display in UI/somewhere else.

If `Calendar1.SelectedDate` is of `DateTime` type:

```
string date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString(
                                      "yyyy/MM/dd", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If `Calendar1.SelectedDate` is of `string` type:

```
string date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                          Calendar1.SelectedDate, 
                         "yyyy/MM/dd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Answer (score 0):

ParseExact converts a string to a datetime, so

```
selectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2012/02/29", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

would work. Not sure why you want to convert a datetime to a datetime??