# How to provide dates in a culture-agnostic way to MS Access OleDb Command?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a C# program. In that program, I select some dates from Access 2010 database and process data. But, I can't access and process data on rows containing dates from a range of **01/12/2014** and **11/12/2014** but I can process remaining dates.

`cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MIN([Vch No]) FROM [" + group + "] WHERE [Entry Date]=#" + date + "#", conn);
long Vch = long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) - 1;`

I get error on line `long Vch = ... - 1;` saying can't get proper Input string. Whereas, it works for other dates either before or after these particular dates.

I declare the date by this code :

`cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Entry Date] FROM [" + group + "]) WHERE [Entry Date]>#" + initDate + "# ORDER BY [Entry Date]", conn);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); dr.Read();
string date = dr["Entry Date"].ToString();`

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Because in what month is `11/12`? Perhaps those dates you deem valid don't give an error, but won't give the proper result either. Supply the date in a culture-invariant way.

Comment: What do you mean by _what month_?

Comment: Can you **please** show me how to do it?

Comment: Well, if you're in the UK `11/12` would be November, if you're in the US `11/12` would be December. So the dates should be ISO, that is YYYY/MM/DD so there's no assumptions

Comment: What can I mean by that? Is `11/12` december 11th, or november 12th? It may be obvious to you, but the computer has to guess, and does so wrong. See [How do you format dates within MS Access Queries to prevent the US/UK issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609944/how-do-you-format-dates-within-ms-access-queries-to-prevent-the-us-uk-issue), for example. If you could provide the _actual exception message_, or better even use the search with it, I'm sure you'll get plenty of results.

Comment: Use datetime query parameters.  They solve many problems, including the one you are experiencing.

Comment: So you mean that sql jet engine and c# compiler may use different forms of representing dates?

Comment: No, the C# compiler doesn't know anything about dates. Show how you declare and initialize `date`. Read the link from my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting you `date` variable to a non culture specific date format, so `YYYY/MM/DD` e.g. **2014/12/01**

If `date` is a C# `DateTime` object, you'll need to call:

```
date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As per [convert datetime to yyyy/MM/dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498049/convert-datetime-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

So:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MIN([Vch No]) FROM [" + group + "] WHERE [Entry Date]=#" +
date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) +
"#", conn);
long Vch = long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) - 1;
```

***EDIT TO ADD***

As per @Gord-Thompson's comment, it's always considered best practise to use parameters where ever possible (generally always!).

So:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT MIN([Vch No]) FROM [@pGroup] WHERE [Entry Date]=@pDate", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pGroup", OleDbType.NVarChar).Value = group;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pDate", OleDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
long Vch = long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) - 1;
```

Try to avoid using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` - see http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ for more details.

Comment: ( cc: @Harshan01 ) Or better yet, use an `OleDbCommand.Parameter` and avoid the date formatting issue completely.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, edited as suggested. I know the `#` for date delimiters are specific to Access hence wasn't sure if they'd still be needed.